# How to implement Client IP based routing using Istio features?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I am trying to achieve **Client IP based routing** using Istio features.

I have two versions of application **V1(Stable)** and **V2(Canary)**. I want to route the traffic to the canary version(V2) of the application if the Client IP is from a particular CIDR block (Mostly the CIDR my org) and all other traffic should be routed to the stable version(V1) which is the live traffic.

Is there any way to achieve this feature using Istio?

Comment: What version of `istio` do you use? What k8s version is used?

Comment: @moonkotte I use the latest version of Istio and the Cluster is of V1.19.

Comment: One more question about `Client IP`: how does traffic go from client to istio mesh? Are there any load balancers, ingress controllers or anything else that can re-write `client IP`?

Comment: Yes. There is a LoadBalancer which is before the Istio ingress which is the entry point of the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

---

Since you have a `load balancer` in front of the kubernetes cluster, first question to address is **preserve** `client IP` because due to NAT `load balancer` opens another session to the internal side to kubernetes cluster and `source IP` is lost. It has to be preserved. This can be done in different ways depending on `load balancer` type used. Please see:

[Source IP address of the original client](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#source-ip-address-of-the-original-client)

---

Next part is to configure a `virtual service` to route the traffic based on `client IP`. It was solutioned for HTTP traffic. Below is a working example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app-vservice
  namespace: test
spec:
  hosts:
  - "app-service"
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        x-forwarded-for:
          exact: 123.123.123.123
    route:
    - destination:
        host: app-service
        subset: v2
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: app-service
        subset: v1
```

[Source - Github issue comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/24852#issuecomment-647831912)

There is also a [comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/24852#issuecomment-647704245) about TCP and usage `addresses` in `ServiceEntry`.